# serializing object to json as ClassName.AttributeName

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a class

```
public class Cust
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CNIC { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to serialize it with notation **ClassName.AttributeName**: "`{\"Cust.Name\":\"sara\",\"Cust.CNIC\":\"123456\"}"` instead of `"{\"Name\":\"sara\",\"CNIC\":\"123456\"}"`?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Cust
{
    [JsonProperty("Cust.Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Cust.CNIC")]
    public string CNIC { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1- The **Quickest dirty solution** (Unless you want to write your **own serialize** method ) is:

```
public class Cust
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = nameof(Cust) + "." + nameof(Cust.Name))]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = nameof(Cust) + "." + nameof(Cust.CNIC))]
    public string CNIC { get; set; }
}
```

**Test :**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Cust customer = new Cust() { Name = "aa", CNIC = "bb" };
    string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
}
```

**Output:**

> {"Cust.Name":"aa","Cust.CNIC":"bb"}

**2- Workaround without reinventing the wheel and writing your own serialze method:**

(No need to use JsonProperty Attribute on the class Properties here)

I left the string manipulation optimization for you to do.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Cust customer = new Cust() { Name = "aa", CNIC = "bb" };
    string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);

    var props = typeof(Cust).GetProperties().ToList();

    foreach(var prop in props)
    {
        string oldPropJosn = String.Format("\"{0}\":", prop.Name);
        string newPropJson = String.Format("\"{0}.{1}\":", nameof(Cust), prop.Name);
        jsonResult = jsonResult.Replace(oldPropJosn, newPropJson);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> {"Cust.Name":"aa","Cust.CNIC":"bb"}

Comment: what if i do want to write my own serialize method to achieve same result?

Comment: @Sana.91 Check the edited answer, it is a workaround without the headache of writing the entire serialize methods again. And it will produce the same result.